# Logical comparison fails when it shouldn't C++

Tags: c++, vector

I've been having an issue where this comparison `if (code->at(i) == guess.at(i))`
is failing on even though it shouldn't as they are both '0': http://puu.sh/bvCRB/c640fb85a4.png

`guess` is a vector of char `s(vector<char> guess){`
and `code` is a pointer to a vector of char `vector<char> * code`

Comment: First value is 0 which is ascii '\0' and second value is 48 which is ascii '0'

Comment: @Polymorphic Potato: Chill out, it barely makes a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice the difference in what Visual Studio displays:

```
Name       Char     Value
code[0]    '\0'      0
guess[0]   '0'       48
```

That is, `'0'` (stored in `guess[0]`) is a character `0`, with an ASCII code `48`, whereas `code[0]` holds `'\0'` (see the backslash which stands for an escape character) which is a special character with an ASCII code `0` (known as a nul terminating character). Thus, they are different.

Comment: I wonder why they are different though, I entred them in the same way

Comment: @Gilligan94: if you use iostreams then the input interpretation depends on data type (int, char), if you use stdio then the interpretation depends on formatting stream. so when you write `int i;cin>>i;` then the input is interpreted as integer, when you write `char c;cin>>c;` then input is interpreted as character

Comment: Indeed, I think I know the issue now. For one of them I pushed back each value and the other I resized and used at and cin to add the values. For the pushback I think I forgot the '' around the numbers so they haven't gone in as characters.

Answer (score 2):

`'0'` and `'\0'`are not the same, even visual studio shows you that their values are different. `'0'` in hexadecimal is `30` and null terminator `'\0'` in hex is `00`. They are not equal and their representation in memory is different, hence your comparison fails. If you look at ascii table you'll see the following:

```
   Oct   Dec   Hex   Char       
   ──────────────────────────
   000   0     00    NUL '\0' 
   060   48    30    0
```

`'\0'` is a special character that is used for example to indicate the end of a c-style string, while `'0'` is just an ascii character.